On the finiteness of moments
Consider a random variable $X$ with full support and assume
$$
 \mathbb{E}(\max\{0,\exp(\beta X)\})^p<+\infty 
$$
for some $\beta>0$ and $p>0$.
Does this imply that
$$
\mathbb{E}(\max\{0,X\})^p<+\infty\quad ?
$$

I'm assuming here that $X$ is real. Also the way you have formulated it we can assume without loss of generality that $X\ge 0$. Then it's fairly straightforward: $\exp(\beta p X)$ is more than some positive constant times $X^p$, so the answer to your question is yes.

$\exp(\beta X)>0.$
